# ImportError: cannot import name HeaderParsingError when run 'psiturk-setup-example'

Tags: java, linux, python-2.7, importerror

I tried to install `psiturk` in my lab machine (Linux).

I can run `pip install psiturk` successfully.

```
$ which psiturk
/home/qian/anaconda/bin/psiturk
```

However, when I run `psiturk-setup-example`, it gives me such error.

Does anybody meet the same problem before? 
The following is the error message I got:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It would be better if you added the error message you get as text and not as screenshot: That way other people may find your answer when they search for fragments of the error and it looks nicer ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) I'm not familiar with the usage of stack overflow. I will put text next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some library missing.

First search the available installed package as `pip search urllib3`.

If you don't find the package, install the package -

Try to install [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

`sudo pip install urllib3`

Comment: @Qian Please accept the answer n might be better to up vote also. ;-) Good luck !!!